# Spring Boot infinite recursion

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using JpaRepository. When I try to read records from controller, it gives me weird huge JSON response.

I am sure this is caused by mappings.

Here is my code:

**Entities: Customer**

```
com.arj.entity.Customer

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4910225916550731446L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 256)
private String name;

@Column(name = "email", length = 256)
private String email;

@Column(name = "phone_number", length = 256)
private String phoneNumber;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<CustomerAddress> customerAddresses = new HashSet<CustomerAddress>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Order> orders;

@Column(name = "date_created")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateCreated;

@Column(name = "is_active", columnDefinition = "BIT default 1", length = 1, nullable = false)
private boolean isActive;

getters and setters ...
}
```

**Entities: Dealer**

```
com.arj.entity.Dealer

@Entity
@Table(name = "dealers")
public class Dealer {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4910225916550731446L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 256)
private String name;

@Column(name = "phone_number", length = 20)
private String phoneNumber;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dealer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>();

@Column(name = "date_created")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateCreated;

@Column(name = "is_active", columnDefinition = "BIT default 1", length = 1, nullable = false)
private boolean isActive;

getters and setters ...
}
```

**Entities: Order**

```
com.arj.entity.Order

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4910225916550731446L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "date_created")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateCreated;

@Column(name = "is_active", columnDefinition = "BIT default 1", length = 1, nullable = false)
private boolean isActive;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer customer;

@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "dealer_id", nullable = true)
private Dealer dealer;

getters and setters ...
}
```

**OrderRepository**

```
com.arj.repository.OrderRepository

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Order t WHERE t.status = :status")
    public List<Order> getAllOrdersByStatus(@Param("status") String status);
}
```

**OrderController**

```
com.arj.controller.api.OrderController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/order")
public class OrderController {
@Autowired
OrderRepository orderRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/type/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> getAllOrdersByStatus(@PathVariable("status") String status) {
    List<Order> orders = orderRepository.getAllOrdersByStatus(status);
    if (orders.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Orders empty");
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Order>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<List<Order>>(orders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

I am getting following message:

> "status":200,"error":"OK","message":"Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.aata.entity.Order[\"customer\"]->com.aata.entity.Customer_$$_jvsteb5_c[\"orders\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.aata.entity.Order[\"customer\"]->com.aata.entity.Customer_$$_jvsteb5_c[\"orders\"

Customer have `OneToMany` for Order
Order have `ManyToOne` for customer

If I pick `customer`, I want to pick `orders` as well
If I pick `order`, I want to show `customer` as well

Comment: Please take a look http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: Yes, my bad, duplicate question. Solved this with: JsonBackReference + JsonManagedReference, thanks @hisener